# Cookies not being set by IIS in HTTP header

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, cookies

I use ASP.NET forms authentication that seems to work ok online but not in my development environment for Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome. As far as I can see IIS is not sending the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header when a page is being requested:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:81/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: nb-NO
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 127.0.0.1:81
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 08 Oct 2014 19:24:58 GMT
Content-Length: 13322
```

I've tried adding `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` to the `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and accessing http://www.example.com:81 instead, but that has no effect. Here are my web.config settings:

```
<!-- ASP.NET forms authentication is enabled by default -->
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <!-- Set the page to redirect to when the user attempts to access a restricted resource -->
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work-around by always setting a dummy cookie if no cookies are sent inside the ASP.NET web page:

```
/// <summary>
/// Force the browser to use cookies if none are in use. 
/// Sets an empty cookie.
/// </summary>
void ForceCookiesIfRequired()
{
    if (Request.Cookies == null || Request.Cookies.Count == 0)
    {
        // No cookies, so set a dummy blank one
        var cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, String.Empty) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) };
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
    }
}

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    // Force the use of cookies if none are sent
    ForceCookiesIfRequired();
}
```

I never had todo this before, has some Microsoft patch or upgrade broken ASP.NET forms authentication? One way to check your own solutions is to clear the cookie I guess. This forces the `Set-Cookie` HTTP header to be sent by the IIS server.